# Laravel - IF statement throwing errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to using Laravel and am attempting to use my first `if` statement but      unfortunately it throws an error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong!
```

Code:

```
{{ @if($includes)
        good
   @else
        bad
}}
```

So I attempted to debug:

```
{{ @if(true)
        good
   @else
        bad
}}
```

then:

```
{{ @if(true === true)
        good
   @else
        bad
}}
```

All fail. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The blade directives do not need to be enclosed in braces.
Remove the {{}}, those are needed only when you try to echo variables.

Also that should be in blade view files only.

```
@if(true === true)
        good
   @else
        bad
@endif
```

Comment: I have just updated the answer to close the if statement